# Multisite: Redirect a deleted site - Best practice?

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting

I need to clean up the web server and delete a few deprecated child sites under my multisite install. What is the best practice for setting up a 301 redirect and deleting the old site?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find lots of '301' htaccess rules and examples here and via searching. But the basic is to redirect an 'old' folder to a 'new' folder. The 'new' folder can be any site or page on a site.

```
RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ /new [L,R=301]
```

That will redirect `www.example.com/old` (any page) to `www.example.com/new` . And the '301' says that it is permanent, so will eventually update and search results for the old page.

This site is great for testing htaccess rules: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

Comment: Gotcha. Would I add that redirect in the top-level (root) htaccess file?

Comment: The reason I ask is that my rules are validating true using that checker you recommend, I have them implemented in the root htaccess file (above the standard WordPress rule) and the redirect still isn't working.

Comment: Edit your question to include your new htaccess, which should be placed in the main site root.